# Adding error bars to a line graph with ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphing, errorbar

I have three y values corresponding to three x values. I just want to have a line graph between these three dots

```
g <- c("1","2","3")
i <- c(181.83,178.74,152.02)
df <- data.frame(g,i)
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=g, y=i)) + geom_line() + geom_point()
```

Using this I get this:

[image]

First of all why does my geom_line() not work? After that I have:

```
se <- c(22.95,22.72,19.2)
p + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=se,ymax=se))
```

And what I get is:

[image]

Why are my errorbars not centered around the data points? Why are they smushed to the bottom? Why do they seem horizontal? What can I do to fix this?

Comment: You can fix the first problem with adding `group = 1` like this `ggplot(df, aes(x = g, y = i, group = 1)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point()`

Comment: Thank you so much! Should I edit out that part of the question because it's resolved?

Answer (score 1):

Alright I figured it out: the `ymin` and `ymax` arguments are telling where the error line starts and ends quite literally, so you can't just put the real standard error value and expect `ggplot2` to figure out where will this error line be centered. So you have to specify it as:

```
geom_errobar(aes(ymin = i - se, ymax = i + se))
```

And finally you get:

[image]

Hope it helps others as well.